# Fast way to calculate customized function on a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I was trying to evaluate a customized function over every point on an n-dimensional grid, after which I can marginalize and do corner plots.

This is conceptually simple but I'm struggling to find a way to do it efficiently. I tried a loop regardless, and it is indeed too slow, especially considering that I will be needing this for more parameters (`a1, a2, a3...`) as well. I was wondering if there is a faster way or any reliable package that could help?

**EDITS:** Sorry that my description of `myfunction` hasn't been very clear, since the function takes some specific external data. Nevertheless here's a sample function that demonstrates it:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

#This gaussian filter is needed to process my data
data = gaussian_filter(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), sigma = 1)
model1 = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
model2 = np.array([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
models = np.array([model1, model2])
```

(This is just a demonstration. The actual data and models are some 500x500-ish 2D arrays.)

and then

```py
from scipy.special import gammaln

def myfunction(params):
    """
    Calculates the log of the Poisson likelihood of generating data 
    given model params and fits. 

    params: array-like, with number entries. For example, 
    if params = np.array([a1, a2]), we generate a model of 
    a1*model1 + a2*model2.
    """
    model_combined = np.sum(models * params[:,None,None], axis=0)
    #Unfortunately I need to process my combined model as well
    model_smeared = gaussian_filter(model_combined, sigma=1)

    #This following line is calculating the log of the Poisson likelihood 
#of each pixel taking its value given the combined model as the expectation 
#value, taking advantage that numpy does element-wise calculations 
#automatically in this case
    loglikelihood_array = data * np.log(model_combined) - model_combined - gammaln(data+1)
    #Sum up the loglikelihoods
    loglikelihood_sum = np.sum(loglikelihood_array)
    return loglikelihood_sum
```

The function itself will return me results immediately, but not so if I just simply write a for-loop to calculate it for, say, 100x100 pairs of parameters.

**EDIT #2** I understand that the for-loop within my shown code (sorry for my sloppiness) is confusing (and thanks for the comments for the broadcasting simplification!), and I've just edited that.

My real problem isn't with the combining of the `models[i]`, but with the implementation of the entire function (again described by a very sloppy for-loop here), and `loglikes` is what I finally wanted:

```py
a1_array = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
a2_array = np.linspace(2, 4, 100)
loglikes = np.empty((100, 100))
for i in range(len(a1_array)):
    for j in range(len(a2_array)):
         loglikes[i][j] = myfunction(np.array([a1_array[i], a2_array[j]]))
```

I think there should be a better way of doing this out there than this for-loop, but was unfortunately unaware of it. When I say more parameters I mean, say adding an `a3_array = np.linspace(3, 5, 100)` and then loglikes will be a 3-dimensional array, and so on.

Thanks again so much for any feedback!

Comment: Can you provide a concrete code example of what goes on in `myfunction(a1, a2)`, with fully defining all arrays and whatnot (they can be short, say, 3x3). And also what would change as you add more arguments in the function?

Comment: Hi @Reti43, thanks, I've updated my question - hope that clarifies what I'm asking a bit!

Comment: Replace your loops with [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Assuming your `model_i` is always a 2D array and params a 1D array of length `models.shape[0]`, the loop can be simplified to `model_combined = np.sum(models * params[:,None,None], axis=0)`. If that's not the case, can you share what shapes your actual data has?

Comment: Thanks, I've simplified my code and further clarified my question. Indeed my actual data is always a 2D array; it is my final results that will have n dimensions (i.e. n entries in my params), and my question is exactly how I could perform like broadcasting over an, e.g. 100x100 array with this entire self-defined function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorising that loop won't save you any time and in fact may make things worse.

Instead of looping through `a1_array` and `a2_array` to create pairs, you can generate all pairs from the get go by putting them in a 100x100x2 array. This operation takes an insignificant amount of time compared to python loops. But when you're actually in the function and you're broadcasting your arrays so that you can do your calculations on data, you're now suddenly dealing with 100x100x2x500x500 arrays. You won't have memory for this and if you rely on file swapping it makes the operations exponentially slower.

Not only are you not saving any time (well, you do for very small arrays but it's the difference between 0.03 s vs 0.005 s), but with python loops you're only using a few 10s of MB of RAM, while with the vectorised approach it skyrockets into the GB.

But out of curiosity, this is how it could be vectorised.

```
import itertools

def vectorised(params):
    model_combined = np.sum(params[...,None,None] * models, axis=2)
    model_smeared = gaussian_filter(model_combined, sigma=1)
    log_array = data * np.log(model_combined) - model_combined - gammaln(data+1)
    return np.sum(log_array, axis=(-2, -1))


np.random.seed(0)

M = 500
N = 100

data = gaussian_filter(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (N, N)), sigma=1)
models = np.random.randint(1, 1000, (2, M, M))

a1 = np.linspace(0, 2, N)
a2 = np.linspace(2, 4, N)
a = np.array(list(itertools.product(a1, a2))).reshape((N, N, 2))

log_sum = vectorised(a)
```

And some benchmarks

[image: 1]

Bottom line, a python loop ran 10000 times just to fetch some array elements takes 0.001 s in its totality. This is insignificant to your function taking 0.01 s for **each** call.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment! You're totally right for this, actually I spent yesterday trying to vectorize the function (for my actual project). It worked and gave me the same result, but it ended up taking 3x more time than the for-loop...so I would stick with the loop I suppose?

Comment: @CuriousNaïveté Yes, stick with the for loop. That's not even remotely the bottleneck of your workflow and even if you optimise that part with vectorisation, you may shave off a few milliseconds and then lose seconds to minutes in your function because the calculations are now not memory efficient.